# Fresco isn't updating Image

Tags: java, android

I have one parent activity which has one SimpleDraweeView. I am using following code for attaching image to SimpleDraweeView,

```
Fresco.initialize(this);  Before setContentView() in onCreate().
```

and call following method into onCreate() method

```
public void ImageLoader(){
        //Image Loading with Fresco...
        uri = Uri.parse(*mypath*);
        Fresco.getImagePipeline().evictFromMemoryCache(uri);
        Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getMainDiskStorageCache().remove(new SimpleCacheKey(uri.toString()));
        Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getSmallImageDiskStorageCache().remove(new SimpleCacheKey(uri.toString()));
        ivMainProfile.setImageURI(uri);
    }
```

here profile image shows accurately. Then I have another activity for changing the profile image that also has SimpleDraweeView. After profile image changed when goes back to mainActivity I have called method **onRestart()** and inside of that called **ImageLoader()** method again but this time Image isn't loaded. Please tell me where is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Call your ImageLoader() in onResume method and make sure the image path is correct.

Comment: ImageLoader() is getting called inside of onResume but it shows a previous image (not shown updated image). somewhere cache problem is there??

Comment: clean your project and run it again. Use breakpoint on imagePath to ensure it changed or not.

Comment: If your image path is from file then we parse it fromFile like -  Uri.fromFile("imagePath")

Comment: Image path is from server and I wrote it like Uri.parse("http://..."+userId+".jpg")